# Время работы динамической памяти в C++

Tags: c++, memory

Написал я 2 программы, одна из которых проходит только половину тестов,(остальные Time LIMIT), а другая проходит все тесты. Меня удивило, почему 2 программа может работать быстрее первой? Ведь идет выделение динамической памяти, что должно быть дольше. Вообщем мне интересно почему 2 программа быстрее?

**#1**

```
...
#include <string.h>
#define N 50100

char s[N], t[N * 2];
...
```

**#2**

```
...
#include <string.h>
#define N 50100

char *s = new char[N], 
     *t = new char[N * 2];
....
```

**Если нужно,  то вот весь код программы**

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#define N 50100

char *s = new char[N], *t = new char[N * 2];
int p[N * 2], j, i, len;

int main()
{
    freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
    freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);

    gets(s);
    gets(t);
    len = strlen(t);
    strcat(t, " ");
    strcat(t, s);
    // prefix function
    p[0] = 0;
    for (i = 1; i < strlen(t); i++) {
        j = p[i - 1];
        while (j > 0 && t[j] != t[i])
            j = p[j - 1];
        p[i] = (t[i] == t[j]) ? j + 1 : j;
        if (p[i] == len)
            printf("%d ", i - 2 * len);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Если нужно то вот условие задачи**

```
Найти все вхождния строки T в строку S.

Формат входных данных
Первые две строки входных данных содержат строки S  и T, соответственно. Длины строк больше 0 и меньше 50000, строки содержат только латинские буквы.

Формат выходных данных
Выведите номера символов, начиная с которых строка T входит в строку S, в порядке возрастания.
```

Comment: во всем другом программы идентичны? тесты проходили много раз или по одному на программу? Может компилировали с разными параметрами.

Comment: А можете запрофилировать? Посчитайте, с какой скоростью какие куски выполняются в каждом из случаев.

Comment: Такую программу (даже 50099 символов в каждой строке) еще надо ухитриться померить. Она за микросекунды должна отрабатывать.

Кстати, автор, а что именно (русскими словами) Вы таким образом ищете (выводите в output.txt)

Comment: @avp: ну, автор говорит, что вываливается time limit -- так что наверное больше десяти секунд.

Comment: Тогда надо бы входные данные (input.txt) посмотреть.

Comment: вываливается за 0.2 секунды XD, вообщем у них разница во времени 0.05 секунды..) но и нтересно, что отправлял раз 5 на тестирующую систему, и все одно и то же, 2 работает быстрее, хотя должно быть, наоборот

Comment: знаю что компилируются они на linux-e

Comment: avp, в этой программе я вывожу все позиции в строке S с которых начинается вхождение строки T, (вообще поиск подстроки t в строке s )

Comment: Тогда не понимаю, зачем вообще надо конкатенировать t и s (с искусственным разделителем (пробелом)) и начинать поиск уже в t?

Странный алгоритм.

А входные данные (хотя бы размеры t и s) можете привести?

Comment: @avp , ну это КМП, обычный алгоритм на префикс функцию..) условие задачи добавил в конец вопроса!

Comment: Объясните для неучей, что такое КМП (может у него какое-то общепринятое название на английском есть?) и что Вы называете "префикс-функцией"?

IMHO разумный алгоритм решения такой задачи это построение для t таблицы сдвигов для каждого ее символа на первом этапе. 

На втором же этапе сравниваем s с t и при несовпадении (или дошли до конца t) прыгаем в s на количество символов в соответствии с построенной на этапе 1 таблицей. 

Т.е. таблица (ее размер видимо strlen(t)+1) описывает "внутренние" повторы в t.

Comment: я померил

первый вариант кода выполняется за 360 тактов, а второй за 15765. так что все как раз наоборот как и должно быть. увеличение скорости выполнения достигается видимо за счет доступа через указатель

Comment: @avp: КМП -- это, видимо, [KMP algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm), поиск подстроки Кнута-Морриса-Пратта.

Comment: А знаете ли Вы, что у вас ненужный квадрат из-за strlen в for (i = 1; i < strlen(t); i++) ? Может в просто в одном варианте забыли заменить на len?

Comment: @Михаил М, возможно компилятор соптимизирует вызовы strlen, т.к. в цикле содержимое t не меняется.

Comment: Язык C++, а строки сишные. Или надо белье надеть (тег исправить), или бижутерию снять (начать таки использовать весь язык).

Answer (score 2):

Да у тебя тут другой косяк.

> ```
> for (i = 1; i < strlen(t); i++) {
> ```

`strlen` вызывается на каждой итерации цикла, поэтому асимптотика становится квадратичной вместо линейной.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению.

Comment: Является. Он как раз про TL говорит.

Comment: Так в обоих случаях то алгоритм идентичен (неоптимален), только выделение памяти разное, или не так?

Comment: @KromStern, речь явно идёт об олимпиадной задаче. В адекватный лимит времени может уложиться квадратичный алгоритм для 10К, в крайнем случае, для 20К. Но что удастся упихать 50К я не верю. Скорее всего, различие с выделением памяти не единственное, тем более, в коде есть строка `len = strlen(t);`.

Comment: Очень похоже на правду.

Comment: Тогда исправьте вопрос, чтобы он был про оптимизацию алгоритма, а не про разницу выделения памяти ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Предположу.
В варианте `1` массив надо инициализировать, компилятор для этого порождает сущность, а в варианте `2` выделяется память без инициализации. Поэтому временные затраты варианта `2` немного меньше чем `1`.
PS: Проверил на разных компиляторах, в одному случае было 0x93, в другом 0x00.

Answer (score 0):

UPD. **Не обратил внимание на возраст вопроса**

Ваша постановка вопроса некорректна в данной ситуации и давайте я объясню почему.

Выделение памяти из кучи действительно более медленный процесс, чем "стековая переменная", но в данном случае этим можно пренебречь, т.к. выделение происходит 1 раз, а не в цикле. И основное время выполнения программы занимает именно цикл.

А для того, чтобы еще больше подогреть у вас интерес к данному вопросу я предлагаю вам создать простой указатель (например s2 и t2) и работать в цикле только с этими указателями, а в самом начале main приравнять их к s и t выделенных любым из ваших способов. Результат вас удивит, т.к. время выполнения программы станет абсолютно одинаковым (во всяком случае в gcc).

Answer (score -1):

Все просто. В первой программе статическое выделение памяти, то есть при компиляции под нужды программы внутри нее уже выделяется область памяти под эти переменные, а во второй программе она выделяется динамически, что требует времени. Делается запрос к ядру ОС, ядро отвечает есть ли память, выделяет блоки и т.д. К тому же если посмотреть, сколько в оперативной памяти занимает процесс, то можно понять несколько вещей: память приписывается к процессу не после выделения ее, а после использования ее участков, соответственно после выделения памяти, вы только договариваетесь с ядром о ее области и только потом начинаете использовать, тогда как в первом случае у вас уже все готово для использования.

Comment: Там наоборот, с динамическим выделением быстрее

Answer (score -6):

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

typedef struct {
  void * ptr;
  uint64_t size;  
} buf_t;

typedef struct {
  int32_t fd;
  buf_t data;
} f_buf_t;

inline uint64_t write_file(f_buf_t buf) {
  return (write(buf.fd, buf.data.ptr, buf.data.size) == buf.data.size);
}

inline buf_t read_file(f_buf_t buf) {
  buf_t ret = (buf_t){ buf.data.ptr, read(buf.fd, buf.data.ptr, buf.data.size)};
  close(buf.fd);
  return ret;
}

inline uint64_t file_size(int32_t fd) {
  return ({ struct stat f_stat; fstat(fd, &f_stat); f_stat.st_size;});
}

inline int32_t open_wo_file(char * file_name) {
  return open(file_name,  O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, (S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR));
}

inline int32_t open_ro_file(char * file_name) {
  return open(file_name, O_RDONLY);
}

inline buf_t true_pseudo_alloc(uint64_t size) {
  return (buf_t){ mmap(NULL, size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, 0, 0), size };
}

inline f_buf_t create_fbuf(int32_t fd) {
  return (f_buf_t){ fd, true_pseudo_alloc(file_size(fd))};
}

inline char * replace(char * str, char ch, char new_ch) {
  char * ret = strchr(str, ch);
  *ret = new_ch;
  return ret;
}

int main(void) {
  buf_t file = read_file(create_fbuf(open_ro_file("input.txt")));
  char * s = file.ptr, * t = replace(s, '\n', 0) + 1;

  buf_t out_file = true_pseudo_alloc(4096);
  sprintf(out_file.ptr, "%lu \n", (strstr(s, t) - s));
//   write_file((f_buf_t){ open_wo_file("output.txt"), out_file });
  write_file((f_buf_t){ 1, out_file });
}
```

Вариации на тему соседнего поста. Сольёт всё, что там у вас есть и ещё останется. Замените реплейс, на обратный реплейс - ещё быстрее будет.

По поводу кмп - там адский оверхед на хеш строки.

Для справки - сравнение на сегодняшнем железе ничего не стоит. Если строки из памяти, то там перекрёстное(десятки вложений) сравнение ничего не стоит.